# Not able to load the static files from express.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, express

I am new to node.js and back-end programming. I am not able to load the static files from express. I am not using the 'public' directory. I need the js files from 'js' folder.
This is the folder structure
[folder structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVsjO.png)

In index.js
I have mentioned: `app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname + '/js'));`

```html
index.html:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sngulsr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.1.3/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-routing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

(these are the files which are not getting loaded)

So, when I run the file, I get $ not defined error since jquery is not getting loaded.

EDIT:
After removing __dirname from app.use image[EDITED_IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAQMI.png)

Comment: Should be just `app.use(express.static('/'));` the way you've set it up, but then you've opened you're entire code base to the client, which is why we use a `/public` folder for that.

Comment: Windows or Linux? What happens if you remove `__dirname` from `app.use`? Getting any errors in console where you're running the web app?

Comment: Thank you! But still the files don't seem to load...

Comment: Windows. Getting this error in this console after removing __dirname from app.use. I have edited my question adding the img of the new error.

Comment: In windows `_dirname` includes backslashes and you're mixing forward/back slashes. Try a relative path instead: change '/js' to './js'. Is this the only `app.use()` you have in your application? Maybe post more of your code...

Comment: as @adeneo said, might make more sense to create a subdirectory in your nodejs project called "public" and then `app.use(express.static('/'))` would serve ALL files in that dir as static. You could move your `js` folder into `public/js/` and you would serve as expected.

Comment: I did that. Still no use. What all files am I supposed to move to public folder? Just the js folder? Or do I need to also move my index.html folder there?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your config slightly

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
```

and then reference all js paths relative to the js folder, for example.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The path you define in the `static` method becomes the root for your static files.

Comment: I can see that only my first js file i.e, jquery.js is getting loaded infinitely multiple times.